# What is alternative for vue2-google-map in developing with Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

What is alternative for [vue2-google-map](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps#readme)? I have a problem with vue-google-map.

I migrated my project from vue2 to vue3, but vue2-google-map component is not working.
There isn't event emitter like @center_changed.
How can I resolve this problem?

```html
<gmap-map
  :center="newCenter"
  :zoom="zoom"
  map-type-id="roadmap"
  style="width: 100%; height: 30vh; min-width: 300px"
  @center_changed="updateCenter"
>
  <gmap-marker
    :icon="{url:'./static/marker3.png'}"
    :position="newPosition"
    @position_changed="changePosition"
    :clickable="false"
    :draggable="true"
  >
  </gmap-marker>
  <gmap-circle
    :center="newCircleCenter"
    :radius="getNewRadius"
    :options="{
      strokeColor: colors.getColor('MAP_ACCENT'),
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 1,
      fillColor: colors.getColor('MAP_ACCENT'),
      fillOpacity: 0.4
    }"
  />
</gmap-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

[vue3-google-map](https://github.com/inocan-group/vue3-google-map#marker) available in `npm` you can use it as a complete replacement.

```
npm i vue3-google-map
```

```
<template>
  <GoogleMap api-key="YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY" style="width: 100%; height: 500px" :center="center" :zoom="15">
    <Marker :options="markerOptions" />
  </GoogleMap>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { GoogleMap, Marker } from "vue3-google-map";

export default defineComponent({
  components: { GoogleMap, Marker },
  setup() {
    const center = { lat: 40.689247, lng: -74.044502 };
    const markerOptions = { position: center, label: "L", title: "LADY LIBERTY" };

    return { center, markerOptions };
  },
});
</script>
```